# Can I buy a US domestic ticket for Europeans visiting the US?

Tags: air-travel, transit

We have relatives visiting from Europe later this year and are meeting them in FL. After a stay there we are planning to have them fly back to NY with us. Is there a problem buying them a ticket on a US airline to do so?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem, so long as your relatives can present identification documents that match the names on the tickets.

You are not asked for your nationality when booking a domestic flight, and there is [no special identification](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) required of aliens at the TSA checkpoint. Furthermore, I don't see how it would ever make sense— economically, politically, or otherwise— for an airline to restrict a particular flight to passengers of a certain nationality.

Comment: "Furthermore, I don't see how it would ever make sense—economically, politically, or otherwise—for an airline to restrict a particular flight to passengers of a certain nationality." Since this is written so widely, I'll chime in and say that several airlines in South America and one or two in Africa do restrict their cheapest tickets to residents only. (They may also only be sold within the country so most searches won't show such tickets.) The economic sense stems from the fact that foreigners will tolerate a higher cost for transport than residents would. But no airlines in the US do this.

Comment: @Calchas Fair enough, but that's not a scenario covered by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I buy a US domestic ticket for Europeans visiting the US?

**YES**.  100%.

> Is there a problem buying them a ticket on a US airline to do so?

**NO**, not at all.

Just make sure the name on the reservation matches their Passport and they're good to go.